# Minimal Material Table Demo ID Column not rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm attempting to create [a minimal material table demo - Note this is a stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo) and the `id` column is not rendering.  Here's the `app.component.ts`:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from "@angular/material";
    class Todo {
      id: string;
      description: string;
      complete: boolean;
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      displayedColumns: ['id', 'description', 'complete'];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Todo>;

      ngOnInit() {
        const todos: Todo[] = [{ id: '123', description: 'Complete me!', complete: false }];
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(todos);
      }
    }
```

And this is the template:

```
    <mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
      </mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common mistake to use type instead of value:

```
displayedColumns: ['id', 'description', 'complete']
```

should be:

```
displayedColumns = ['id', 'description', 'complete']
```

Also you have to configure all the columns in html. So keep only those columns you're actually using.

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-qs1fy9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**